# Find Nth occurrence of a string using Regex

Tags: bash

So I have a string at the beginning of a line and can find all of them. I am using ^$string to match and I have thousands of these and an error occurs on a specific line. Let's say I was trying to get to the 100th occurrence of this pattern how would I do so?

For example, I can grep ^$string and list all but I would like to find a specific one.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What's the expected behaviour if there are less than 100 matches?

Comment: I like Kent's answer, but I'll also mention: `sed '100!d; 100q'` to print the 100th line and immediately quit. Useful if for example you've saved the full grep output, to query multiple times. There's also `awk '/regex/ && ++c==100 {print; exit}` but it's generally slower than `grep`.

Comment: @dan Even `sed '100!d;q'`. `100` in front of `q` is not necessary. Note that both `sed` and `awk` solutions you mentioned are **not** equivalent to Kent's solution when there are less than 100 matches: `sed` and `awk` solutions will print out nothing whereas Kent's solution will print out the last match.

Answer (score 1):

grep has `-m / --max-count` option:

```
grep -m100 '^String' | tail -1
```

will give you the 100th matched line.

Note:

- the `-m100` will make grep stop reading the input file if 100 matches are hit. It's pretty useful if you are reading a huge file
- the `tail` command is very fast since it doesn't read the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to print only a single line of your `grep`'s output :

```
grep "^$string" inputFile | sed -n '100p'
```

`-n` has output disabled by default, `100p` prints the input to the output stream for the 100th line only.

Or as [@dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13919668/) mentions in the comments :

```
grep "^$string" inputFile | sed '100!d;q'
```

Comment: This is the better option because I was able get a more refined search based on what I was looking to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @trazinaz Thanks, consider accepting my answer then, it helps people with similar questions in the future ! It's the checkmark under the voting arrows on the left of the answer.

Comment: `100` in front of `q` command is not necessary.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin right, thanks !